# Mostrar data atual no EditorFor Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Pessoal gostaria de saber como inserir a data atual em um @Html.EditorFor?
Já procurei em vários lugares mas até agora não consegui nada.

Comment: Sem quaisquer detalhes adicionais não costuma ajudar, veja isto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124434/display-only-date-and-no-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Html.EditorFor` é um componente que se liga a algum item do seu *Model* (ou ainda *ViewModel*, se for o caso). Portanto, se sua classe tem um campo assim:

```cs
public DateTime MeuCampoData { get; set; }
```

Você apenas deve definir o campo `MeuCampoData` com a data atual no *Controller*.

```cs
meuModel.MeuCampoData = DateTime.Now;
```

Atenção para ações de criar registros (como o caso de `Create`). Ao fazer isto:

```cs
return View();
```

Você está passando um *Model* **vazio** para a *View*. Para estes casos, é preciso definir um *Model* novo em *Controller*, definir a data e aí passar este *Model* para a *View*:

```cs
var meuModel = new MeuModel {
    meuModel.MeuCampoData = DateTime.Now;
};
return View(meuModel);
```

Feito isto corretamente, `@Html.EditorFor()` exibirá corretamente a data atual:

```cs
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeuCampoData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.Label(@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), new { @class = "css-class" })
```